# React Native CLI : Run IOS in windows PC

Tags: android, react-native, mobile

I just want to know, Is there any way to run or test the IOS app in the windows emulator, I just want to test if my app can run in the IOS too using emulator etc., yet in my `Android` using `npx react-native run-android` it works fine and now I just want to test the command which is `npx react-native run-ios` but I think it only works at IOS instead windows, Is there any chance to run it in the emulator of android studio? or should I used VMWare?

I have already app using React Native -CLI and I want to test and run it on the IOS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Mac is required to build projects with native code for iOS. You can follow the Expo CLI Quickstart to learn how to build your app using Expo instead.
[React-Native Getting Started](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup#unsupported)

Comment: I have already app using React Native -CLI and I want to test and run it on the IOS, yet only android I've tested

Comment: So, VMWare is the easiest solution then. Otherwise there are ways to dual boot a hackintosh. but that is not a straightforward way to do on a windows PC.